# Recurring event in calendar showing as a single event in list view

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have a calendar with recurring events. When I try to create a view in list and using 'group by' month & year, it is not showing recurring items separately in each month category.

How can I get a list view to show all entries in the series with each day having different entries?

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? is it SP2013 on-premises or SP online or is it SP 2010?

Comment: it is sharepoint 2010 i am using. I think it is related to the calculated column formula which i am using.

Comment: Please look into it ..https://blog.appliedis.com/2013/01/25/solving-the-sharepoint-2010-calendar-recurrence-bug/

Comment: i am able to see diferrent events in calendar but in list view there comes only one row in the start of month date. what i want is that i should be able to view them in every month in which it is scheduled if use group by month on that list..

Comment: is my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In SharePoint 2010, Recurring events will be stored only as a single
>   item with a rule attached to show all recurrences in the calendar view
>   or when the calendar is linked to Outlook.
>
> The only way to have individual events out of a recurring event is to
>   edit any single event in the calendar view and save them without
>   modification. This will generate single events out of the recurring
>   event.
>
> *The problem then is whenever you edit the series this events won't be part of the recurring event. The single events also won't be updated.*

Comment: Yes Hardik, It worked fine. Are you sure there is no other way to avoid this issue? Although your workaround works just fine, but it wont be feasible everytime. Thanks